# finding version of component services on remote machine

Tags: c#, service, components

how to get version of installed component services on remote machine using c#?

---

this is for local machine...can anyone tell how to access for remote machine?

```
COMSVCSLib.MtsGrpClass group = new COMSVCSLib.MtsGrpClass();

for (int i = 0; i < group.Count; i++)
{
    object item = null;
    group.Item(i, out item);
    COMSVCSLib.COMEvents events = (COMSVCSLib.COMEvents)item;

    ListBox1.Items.Add(events.GetProcessID().ToString( ) + ":" +
    events.PackageGuid + ":" + events.PackageName);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
    item = null;
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(events);
    events = null;
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(group);
group = null;
```

Comment: You need to use WMI, look at the `System.Management` namespace.